# Freezes during or just after login on Dell XPS 15 9560

Tags: dell, xps

I installed 18.04 LTS and it froze on the lock screen. Yesterday I tried 18.10 and this got stuck after about 20 seconds of using it.

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There are several how-tos available for running Ubuntu on this Dell XPS 15 9560.

To get rid of the freezing add these boot parameters during boot. Access the GRUB menu and press <kbd>E</kbd>, then add this text to the end of the line beginning with `linux`:

```
nouveau.modeset=0 acpi_osi=Linux acpi_rev_override=1
```

Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

Now edit the file `/etc/default/grub` with root permission, for example using the command

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

In the file, edit the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` so after your edit it says:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_rev_override=1 acpi_osi=Linux nouveau.modeset=0 quiet splash"
```

Save the file and exit, and run

```
sudo update-grub
```